# TableToTable gives unexpected character after line continuation character?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I'm working on updating a python script from arcmap 9.3.1 to 10.2.1 and im getting an error for "unexpected character after line continuation character" and im unable to diagnose the character.

```
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(sde_parcel_base_temp, sde, "parcel_base", "", "pin \"PIN\" true true false 10 Text 0 0 ,First,#,"+ sde_parcel_base_temp +",PIN,-1,-1;pwd \"PWD\" true true false 13 Text 0 0 ,First,#,"+ sde_parcel_base_temp +",PWD,-1,-1;add_num \"Address Number\" true true false 10 Text 0 0 ,First,#,"+ sde_parcel_base_temp +",add_num,-1,-1;add_prefix \"Address Prefix\" true true false 1 Text 0 0 ,First,#,"+ sde_parcel_base_temp +",add_prefix,-1,-1;add_strt \"Address Street\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,"+ sde_parcel_base_temp +",add_strt,-1,-1;add_type \"Address Type\" true true false 10 Text 0 0 ,First,#,"+ sde_parcel_base_temp +",add_type,-1,-1;add_sdir \"Address Suffix\" true true false 2 Text 0 0 ,First,#,"+ sde_parcel_base_temp +",add_sdir,-1,-1;add_munic \"Address Municipality\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,"+ sde_parcel_base_temp +",prop_city,-1,-1;add_zip \"Address ZIP\" true true false 10 Text 0 0 ,First,#,"+ sde_parcel_base_temp +",prop_zip,-1,-1;add_full \"Full Street Address\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,"+ sde_parcel_base_temp +",prop_street,-1,-1;ownr_name1 \"Owner Name 1\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,"+ sde_parcel_base_temp +",owner1,0,49;ownr_name2 \"Owner Name 2\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,"+ sde_parcel_base_temp +",owner2,0,49;ownr_addr \"Owner Address\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,"+ sde_parcel_base_temp +",own_street,-1,-1;ownr_city \"Owner City\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,"+ sde_parcel_base_temp +",own_city,-1,-1;ownr_state \"Owner State\" true true false 2 Text 0 0 ,First,#,"+ sde_parcel_base_temp +",own_state,-1,-1;ownr_zip \"Owner Zip\" true true false 10 Text 0 0 ,First,#,"+ sde_parcel_base_temp +",own_zip,-1,-1;acres "\Legal Acreage\" true true false 50 Double 0 0 ,First,#,"+ sde_parcel_base_temp +",legal_acreage,-1,-1;prop_code \"Property Class Code\" true true false 10 Text 0 0 ,First,#,"+ sde_parcel_base_temp +",property_class,-1,-1;nghbr_code \"Neighborhood Code\" true true false 10 Text 0 0 ,First,#,"+ sde_parcel_base_temp +",neighborhood,-1,-1;lgl1 \"Legal Line 1\" true true false 80 Text 0 0 ,First,#,"+ sde_parcel_base_temp +",lrsn,-1,-1;lgl2 \"Legal Line 2\" true true false 80 Text 0 0 ,First,#,"+ sde_parcel_base_temp +",lrsn,-1,-1;lgl3 \"Legal Line 3\" true true false 80 Text 0 0 ,First,#,"+ sde_parcel_base_temp +",lrsn,-1,-1;lgl4 \"Legal Line 4\" true true false 80 Text 0 0 ,First,#,"+ sde_parcel_base_temp +",lrsn,-1,-1;lgl5 \"Legal Line 5\" true true false 80 Text 0 0 ,First,#,"+ sde_parcel_base_temp +",lrsn,-1,-1;lgl6 \"Legal Line 6\" true true false 80 Text 0 0 ,First,#,"+ sde_parcel_base_temp +",lrsn,-1,-1;lrsn \"Proval LRSN\" true true false 50 Long 0 0 ,First,#,"+ sde_parcel_base_temp +",lrsn,-1,-1;updated \"Last Update\" true true false 50 Date 0 0 ,First,#,"+ sde_parcel_base_temp +",last_update,-1,-1", "")
```

Above is the part of the script giving me problems.  Anybody with a trained eye able to point out my problem for me?

Comment: As a side note, you might find it easier to use `str.format()` to build you long string instead of concatenation.

Comment: Although technically I agree that there is a Python rather than ArcPy cause for this error, the "unexpected character after line continuation character" error message has not been recorded anywhere else on this site and crops up so frequently when people start to use ArcPy that I am voting to re-open it.

Comment: I agree with PolyGeo. We would seriously narrow the scope of GIS.SE if we took this approach. For instance, almost all of our HTML/JavaScript questions could be closed, because it is more often a case of bad programming logic rather than any issue with GIS.

Answer (score 7):

`acres "\Legal Acreage\" true true false 50 Double`

You've escaped the `L` here rather than the double quote.